# Query to find out the duplicate rows among two DataTable?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, datatable, match

I have an excel sheet with columns:

```
Id,Data
```

I have a table in sql server database:

```
Id,Data
```

I have derived rows of both in two different `DataTables`, now I want to detect rows which are common in both excel and database table and store the duplicates in another `DataTable`.
Something like this:

```
OleDbCommand command1 = new OleDbCommand("select * from [Sheet1$]",connection);
DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
try
{
    OleDbDataAdapter da2 = new OleDbDataAdapter(command1);
    da2.Fill(dt2);
}
catch { }
```

Answer (score 1):

try out using linq way like this

```
var matched = from table1 in dt1.AsEnumerable()
               join table2 in dt2.AsEnumerable() on 
             table1.Field<int>("ID") equals table2.Field<int>("ID")
             where table1.Field<string>("Data") == table2.Field<string>("Data")
             select table1;
```

Comment: I am not matching data between two sql tables, i am matching data between excel sheet and sql table. Wil the above approach work for the same?

Comment: @user1557976- yes this will work once you get data in DataTable from any source...

Comment: I might sound a complete tubelight here but doesnt table1 and table2 refer to sql server table? SOrry i am a total newbie

Comment: @user1557976- not that is not the case table1 and table2 are DataTable which is not related to sql server that can be generated from any data source like excel or form sql server or from oracle server...read about datatable you will get what i m talking about

Comment: @user1557976- dont forget to upvote and mark answer as accpeted if it work for you...

Comment: the last line select table1;
is red cant fix it

Comment: @user1557976 - have you included namespace system.Linq at the top

Comment: if you want to find only complete duplicates, you need to explicitly type all the columns. Otherwise there can be a situation when fields `Data` are equal, but fields `Data1` are not equal and row returned anyway.

Comment: @PranayRana ok i managed to remove red lines, can i display this var maatched data into a gridview?

Comment: GridView is not visible i dont know why,even though visibility is true.
  var matched = from table1 in dt4.AsEnumerable()
                              join table2 in oltlb.AsEnumerable() on
                            table1.Field<int>("ID") equals table2.Field<int>("ID")
                              where table1.Field<string>("Data") == table2.Field<string>("Data")
                              select table1;
                GridView1.DataSource = matched;

Comment: @user1557976 - try like this it will work for you, just update binding line  'GridView1.DataSource = matched.ToList();'

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18586/discussion-between-user1557976-and-pranay-rana)

Comment: @PranayRana i have corrected one of my faults but still i am getting error on line : 
table1.Field<int>("id") equals table2.Field<int>("id") 
which says Specified cast is not valid.

Comment: @Arbaaz - is id field is of type int or is nullable int like int?..just check type of id column in data table

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18593/discussion-between-arbaaz-and-pranay-rana)

Comment: @PranayRana its int and can be null
do you want to see entire code?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find duplicates, you can try this

```
var result = table1.AsEnumerable().Intersect(table2.AsEnumerable()).Select(x => x);
```

If you want to eliminate duplicates from union, you can try this

```
var result = table1.AsEnumerable().Union(table2.AsEnumerable()).Select(x => x);
```